# jQuery each() loop does not return control when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want return true/false from my function when the `if` condition is met. However it's not returning `true`, every time it returns `false`. Please help me. Thanks.

```js
function catExists(cName) {
  $("#room_has_cat_table tbody tr td:first-child").each(function(index, item) {
    var existingCat = $(this).text();
    alert(existingCat);
    
    if (existingCat == cName) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Your return true returns from the inner `function(index, item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your logic is because you cannot `return` a value from an anonymous function.

To correct your logic define a boolean variable which you can update inside the loop when a match is found:

```js
function foo(cName) {
  let matchFound = false;

  $("#room_has_cat_table tbody tr td:first-child").each(function() {
    var existingCat = $(this).text();
    if (existingCat == cName) {
      matchFound = true;
      return; // exit the each() loop
    }
  });

  return matchFound;
}
```

***However***, a better approach entirely would be to use `filter()` to find the match. This avoids the need for the explicit loop:

```js
let matchFound = $("#room_has_cat_table tbody tr td:first-child").filter((i, el) => el.innerText.trim() === cName).length !== 0;
```